# Joda not formatting dates on or before 1/1/1582?

Tags: jodatime

I am using the latest version of Joda DateTime (2.9.2) and when I try to format a Java Date that is 1/1/1582 or earlier Joda does not correctly format the date. Below is a sample program to show this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class JodaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date dt = sdf.parse("1/1/1582");
        System.out.println("Date: " + dt);
        System.out.println("Date Formatted via SDF: " + sdf.format(dt));

        DateTime joda = new DateTime(dt);
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
        fmt.withLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("Joda: " + fmt.print(joda));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1582
Date Formatted via SDF: 01/01/1582
Joda: 11-Jan-82

SimpleDateFormat formats the date correctly as 1/1/1582 but Joda formats it as 1/11/1582.
```

Comment: The default in Joda-Time is the proleptic gregorian calendar. You will need something like `DateTime joda = new DateTime(dt, GJChronology.getInstance());`

Comment: That worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [spec](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/GJChronology.html);

> The Gregorian calendar replaced the Julian calendar, and the point in
>   time when this chronology switches can be controlled using the second
>   parameter of the getInstance method. By default this cutover is set to
>   the date the Gregorian calendar was first instituted, October 15,
>   1582.
>
> Before this date, this chronology uses the proleptic Julian calendar
>   (proleptic means extending indefinitely). The Julian calendar has leap
>   years every four years, whereas the Gregorian has special rules for
>   100 and 400 years. A meaningful result will thus be obtained for all
>   input values. However before 8 CE, Julian leap years were irregular,
>   and before 45 BCE there was no Julian calendar.

You must use `org.joda.time.chrono.GJChronology` to format date earlier from October 15, 1582.

You can try like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date dt = sdf.parse("1/1/1582");
        System.out.println("Date: " + dt);
        System.out.println("Date Formatted via SDF: " + sdf.format(dt));

        DateTime joda = new DateTime(dt, GJChronology.getInstance());
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
        fmt.withLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("Joda: " + fmt.print(joda));
    }
```

And the output is;

```
Date: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 VET 1582
Date Formatted via SDF: 01/01/1582
Joda: 01-Oca-82
```